# Ensure custom events fire after h5validate events

Tags: html, jquery, validation

I'm running into an issue with [H5Validate](https://github.com/ericelliott/h5Validate) where their events are being triggered after to the custom events I have implemented, effectively preventing my events from being triggered because they're based on the H5validate events.

The workaround I'm currently using is setting H5validate's trigger event to `change` or `$('#form').h5Validate({ change: true });` while triggering my events on `focusout`.

Although this works, I'd prefer to find a method to allow my events to fire after H5validate's so I can use the `keyup` event for more of a 'live validation' feel and to ensure changes keep the button disabled prior to `focusout` thus allowing users to move forward, not see the server side validation pop.

It actually works occasionally. How can I ensure my events will trigger after h5validate's without doing something hacky like a `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing. Why do you need your own event handlers in the first place?

What are you trying to accomplish with them?

If you need to check the whole form, you can do so like this:

```
$form.bind('formValidated', function (event, data) {
  // do stuff after whole form is validated
});

// trigger whole-form validation check
$form.h5Validate('allValid');
```

Comment: I'm just trying to update the button live as fields validate or invalidate. This makes sense and I'll give it a go. I'm not very well equipped when it comes to js, more of a designer/css dev, so I sometimes overlook pre-configured callbacks and built in functionality in plugins when reading through the code. Appreciate you setting me straight.